# Trying to do a basic code but generate an error

Tags: python, object, int, callable

Just trying some code out:

```
a_leg = 5
b_leg = 5

hyp = (a_leg**2)(b_leg**2)
print(hyp)
```

I get the below error:

```
hyp = (a_leg**2)(b_leg**2)
```

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

What does this mean? I know it is very basic but will appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: I try to put it in a function and still get the same error:

def hyp_triangle(a_leg,b_leg):
    hyp = (a_leg**2)(b_leg**2)
    return hyp

print(hyp_triangle(5,4))

Comment: If you want to multiply them, you might want to add an `*` like `hyp = (a_leg**2) * (b_leg**2)` otherwise it will suggest, that you want to call this expression `(a_leg**2)` with an argument of this expression `(b_leg**2)`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this because of

```
hyp = (a_leg**2)(b_leg**2)
```

In programming languages you have to explicitly use operators. In this case, the correct code would be:

```
hyp = (a_leg**2)*(b_leg**2)
```

notice the `*` between those two brackets.

Answer (score -1):

You are getting this error because:

```
(a_leg**2)
```

returns an integer that is not callable. You can make a function to calculate the hypotenuse like these:

```
from math import sqrt

a_leg = 5
b_leg = 5

def hyp(a, b):
    h = sqrt((a**2) + (b**2))
    return h

print(hyp(a_leg, b_leg))
```